# Java library for fast multiplication of very big numbers

Tags: java, biginteger, multiplication

I am writing a program which requires multiplication of very big numbers (million digit) at a point. Can anyone suggest a java library for a fast multiplication of big numbers? I have found [this](https://github.com/tbuktu/ntru/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sf/ntru/arith/Sch%C3%B6nhageStrassen.java), but I'm not sure if this is the right solution, so I'm trying to find another to try.

Comment: FWIW, thanks for the link. It will help me implement Schönhage-Strassen into my own (Object Pascal based) implementation of BigIntegers. I already have Karatsuba and Toom-Cook implemented, but Schönhage-Strassen was a little beyond my horizon, until now. <g>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution you link to — Schönhage-Strassen — is indeed a good way to make multiplying very very large BigIntegers faster.

Due to the big overhead, it is not faster for much smaller BigIntegers, so you can use this, recursively down to a certain threshold (you'll have to find out empirically what that theshold is) and then use BigInteger's own multiplication, which already implements the Toom-Cook and Karatsuba divide-and-conquer algorithms (since Java 8, IIRC), also recursively down to certain thresholds.

**Forget the answers telling you to use Karatsuba.** Not only does Java implement this already, as well as the even faster (for very large BigIntegers) Toom-Cook algorithm, it is also a lot slower (for such huge values) than Schönhage-Strassen.

#### Conclusion

Again: for small values, use simple schoolbook multiplication (but using – unsigned – integers as "digits" or "bigits"). For much larger values, use Karatsuba (which is a recursive algorithm, breaking large BigIntegers down to several smaller ones and multiplying these -- a divide-and-conquer algorithm). For even larger BigIntegers, use Toom-Cook (also a divide-and-conquer). For very large BigIntegers, use Schönhage-Strassen (IIRC, an FFT-based algorithm). Note that **Java already implements schoolbook (or "base case"), Karatsuba and Toom-Cook multiplications, for differently sized Bigintegers**. It does not implement Schönhage-Strassen yet.

But even with all these optimizations, multiplications of very huge values tend to be slow, so don't expect miracles.

---

### Note:

The Schönhage-Strassen algorithm you link to reverts to Karatsuba for smaller sub-products. Instead of Karatsuba, revert to the, since then (Christmas day 2012), much improved implementation in BigInteger and simply use `BigInteger::multiply()` directly, instead of Karatsuba. You may also have to change the thresholds used.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my thinking abilities the [Karatsuba Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-set-2-karatsuba-algorithm-for-fast-multiplication/) can be implemented in this manner:

[This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-set-2-karatsuba-algorithm-for-fast-multiplication/) link provides with a C++ implementation of the same, this can be easily adopted for the Java like implementation easily as well.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

class Karatsuba {
    private final static BigInteger ZERO = new BigInteger("0");

    public static BigInteger karatsuba(BigInteger x, BigInteger y) {

        // cutoff to brute force
        int N = Math.max(x.bitLength(), y.bitLength());
        if (N <= 2000) return x.multiply(y);                // optimize this parameter

        // number of bits divided by 2, rounded up
        N = (N / 2) + (N % 2);

        // x = a + 2^N b,   y = c + 2^N d
        BigInteger b = x.shiftRight(N);
        BigInteger a = x.subtract(b.shiftLeft(N));
        BigInteger d = y.shiftRight(N);
        BigInteger c = y.subtract(d.shiftLeft(N));

        // compute sub-expressions
        BigInteger ac    = karatsuba(a, c);
        BigInteger bd    = karatsuba(b, d);
        BigInteger abcd  = karatsuba(a.add(b), c.add(d));

        return ac.add(abcd.subtract(ac).subtract(bd).shiftLeft(N)).add(bd.shiftLeft(2*N));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start, stop, elapsed;
        Random random = new Random();
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        BigInteger a = new BigInteger(N, random);
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger(N, random);

        start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        BigInteger c = karatsuba(a, b);
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        StdOut.println(stop - start);

        start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        BigInteger d = a.multiply(b);
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        StdOut.println(stop - start);

        StdOut.println((c.equals(d)));
    }
}
```

Hope this answers your question well.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: @N00b Pr0grammer - thankyou for your answer. I compiled the code for N=1000000000, and got the following output: 
"5007448
1136159
true"
I am a bit confused, karatsuba is taking longer to do the multiplication?

Comment: Did you do a comparison of some sort with any other implementations?

Comment: no, not yet. I just ran your code as it is. just put  N=1000000000

Comment: Based on need, that can be modified if you find any bottlenecks. Please do let me know if you benchmark against any other implementation. I would be interested to know!

Comment: so karatsuba is taking longer than normal BitInteger multiplication?

Comment: @lexicore - I don't see how that link is related to my question?

Comment: @user1340852 Your `main` method measures and prints run times, obviously for benchmarking purposes. I wanted to provide more background on benchmarking as it's not that easy as it seems. Naive implementations (like yours) may give incorrect results and lead to incorrect conclusions. The question I've linked to is a "go to" SO question on microbenchmarking.

Comment: Plus one to that @lexicore

Comment: Karatsuba is nice for large BigIntegers (several thousand digits), beyond that there are even better algorithms. Note that Java's BigInteger *does* use Karatsuba and Toom Cook 3-way in its BigInteger code already. So proposing Karatsuba is unnecessary.

Comment: @user1340852: For *large* BigIntegers, Karatsuba is *faster*, but there are even faster algorithms for huge BigIntegers (like yours). Note that Java already uses the faster Toom Cook 3-way algorithm for such huge BigIntegers. Karatsuba and Toom-Cook are generally faster, but their initial overhead precludes them from being used for relatively small BigIntegers.